# what happened when connection created using oracle odp.net is closed or disposed?

Tags: c#, oracle

addition to above question I have below concern with odp.net connection management

1. If no pooling is defined externally in connection string,It would be possible to use the closed connection object?
2. How to get the count of connection objects open or available for use?
3. How programmatically I can assign a connection obect to a specific group of users?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> If no pooling is defined externally in connection string,It would be
>   possible to use the closed connection object?

NO, if connection pooling is used then the closed connection goes back to pooled connection object for re-use; if-not then your connection instance destroyed and can't be re-used. You will have to re-create a connection instance again for use.

> How to get the count of connection objects open or available for use?

That's not a good practice to have multiple connection instance open. Rather you should use a `Using(){ ... }` block; so that your connection object gets disposed off when done. You should rather use a singleton pattern probably to get a single connection to use.

> How programmatically I can assign a connection obect to a specific
>   group of users?

I am not sure what you mean by *assign to specific group of users*. You might want to clarify.

Comment: How programmatically I can assign a connection object to a specific group of users?                                                                                                        I have to allocate the connection object based on department from where user is logged into the application irrespective of the number of users from the specific department.